# How to handle the dart excepiton of invalid zlib bytes

Tags: error-handling, dart

I've try to implement a function which take zlib bytes as argument using `ZLIB` of `dart:io`. And I want the function to catch the error caused by invalid zlib bytes.

However, I couldn't catch it. Because, it's class is a private class.

Here is an example code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
main() {
  try {
    ZLIB.decode([1,2,3,4,5]);
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
    // InternalError: 'Filter error, bad data'
  }
}
```

I think it can be catched with `if (e.toString() == "InternalError: 'Filter error, bad data'")` in the `catch(e)` block. But, `toString()` is not enough to identify a exception or a error.

What is the best way to handle this error exclude the above string comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are catching the exception but sadly the exception doesn't provide more information about the cause.
There is nothing you can do about it beside filing a bug report/feature request for improved error messages.